# what is the image of $\partial( 1_{S^n})$ for the exact sequence for the fibration $X \to E \to S^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

what is the image of $\partial 1_{S^n}$ where $\cdots \pi_n(S^n)\rightarrow \pi_{n-1}(X) \rightarrow \pi_{n-1}(B)\rightarrow\cdots$

Comment: What fibration?

Comment: Sean : any fibration $X \rightarrow B$ with fibre $S^n$

Comment: The sequence you have written is not, however, one with fibre $S^n$, but rather one with fibre $X$ and base $S^n$.  If you really mean $S^n \to X \to B$, then the sequence is
$$ \cdots \to \pi_{n+1}B \to \pi_n S^n \to \pi_n X \to \pi_n B \cdots$$.


Comment: sorry. I's an error. The fibration is $X \rightarrow E \rightarrow S^n$

Comment: If this answer is sufficient for your purposes, why not accept it?

Answer (score 4):

Any fibration $X \to E \to S^n$ up to fiber homotopy equivalence is given by the "clutching construction" applied to a map $f: S^{n-1} \to G(X)$, where $G(X)$ denotes the topological monoid of self homotopy equivalences of $X$. Let $e: G(X) \to X$ be the evaluation map (evaluate an equivalence at the basepoint of $X$). The answer to your question is given by taking the homotopy class of the composition
$$
S^{n-1} \overset{f}\to G(X) \overset{e} \to X .
$$
Note on the clutching construction: Given $f$ as above, form $E = (D^n_- \times X) \cup (D^n_+ \times X)$ where the gluing is done along the equivalence 
$S^{n-1} \times X \to S^{n-1}\times X$ given by $(x,v) \mapsto (x,g(x)(v))$.  The first factor
projection $E \to S^n$ gives your fibration up to fiberwise equivalence. Small technical point: clutching doesn't give a fibration necessarily (it is what one calls a quasifibration), so we have to convert the map to a fibration in the usual way. However, if we had started with a map $S^{n-1} \to \text{homeo}(X)$ it would clutch to a fiber bundle.

Comment: John: Thanks John. I have some questions for your answer. First, two fibrations $F \to E \to \B$ and $F^prime \to E^prime \to \B^prime$ are equivalent means that $F=F^prime$, $B=B^prime$ and there is a homotopy equivalence $f:E \to E^prime$? Second, how prove the fact that any fibration is fiber homotopy equivalent by the "clutching construction". If a good referece, please recommend.

Comment: See page 22 Hatcher's online $K$-book for a description of the clutching construction in the vector bundle case. The case of a fibration is basically the same. For the fibration case, see Brayton Gray's paper, *On the iterated suspension,* Topology ** 27 ** (1988), no. 3, 301-310.

Comment: John: Tkanks John. I will study them.